# Heroku app crashes when I try to post an image to server from client

Tags: heroku

I've successfully deployed a CRUD app on Heroku. And everything works fine on the deployed web app until I send a POST request to Heroku to post a picture to the server that then sends to S3. Everything works fine, including the picture post request, locally. However I get the following error message when I hit the deployed heroku server.

```
POST https://backend.herokuapp.com/ 503 (Service Unavailable)

Access to fetch at 'https://backend.herokuapp.com/' from origin 'https://frontend.netlify.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

bundle.esm.js:63 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network error: Failed to fetch
    at new t (bundle.esm.js:63)
    at Object.error (bundle.esm.js:1030)
    at g (Observable.js:140)
    at O (Observable.js:179)
    at e.value (Observable.js:240)
    at bundle.esm.js:869
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.error (bundle.esm.js:869)
    at g (Observable.js:140)
    at O (Observable.js:179)
```

This is my code to save the POSTed picture on the server, send it to S3, and then delete the photo on the server.

```
import * as shortid from "shortid";
import { createWriteStream, createReadStream, unlinkSync } from "fs";

const aws = require("aws-sdk");

aws.config.update({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_secretAccessKey
});
const BUCKET_NAME = "dormsurf";

const s3 = new aws.S3();

const storeUpload = async (stream: any, mimetype: string): Promise<any> => {
  // aseq2
  const extension = mimetype.split("/")[1];
  console.log("extension: ", extension);
  const id = `${shortid.generate()}.${extension}`;
  const path = `src/images/${id}`;
  console.log("path", path);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    stream
      .pipe(createWriteStream(path))
      .on("finish", () => resolve({ id, path }))
      .on("error", reject)
  );
};

export const processUpload = async (upload: any) => {
  const { stream, mimetype } = await upload;
  const { id } = await storeUpload(stream, mimetype);
  console.log("id");
  console.log(id);

  var params = {
    Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: `listings_images/${id}`,
    Body: createReadStream(`src/images/${id}`)
  };
  s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error in callback");
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("success");
    console.log(data);
    try {
      unlinkSync(`src/images/${id}`);
      //file removed
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  });
  return id;
};
```

Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

this error is a CORS error fix this error using proxy 
call you backend api using this proxy `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`
in your front call api like this

`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://backend.herokuapp.com/`

Comment: I am able to do get/post requests just fine but for some reason when I upload a file (using apollo-upload-client) in the deployed server it throws that error. Looking at this https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client/issues/131 it seems like the file might be too large? But then i'm not sure how to fix :/